# 3-0 wins in Super Over (Bowled out)

Tags: icc, cricket

Has there been a game in T20I where the game was tied and a team won 3-0 during the subsequent bowl-out?

If yes,

- The game was between which two teams?
- Who scored hits in the bowl-out?
- Who missed the wickets in the bowl-out?

Comment: This looks more like a quiz question than an actual question. Could you please rephrase it, if any actual information is required? Thanks.

Comment: It's formal question only frnd.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this scenario occurred when [India beat Pakistan](http://www.espncricinfo.com/twenty20wc/engine/match/287862.html) during the group stage of World Cup T20 in 2007.

Players who scored hits in bowl-out.

1. Virender Sehwag
2. Harbhajan Singh
3. Robin Uthappa

Players who missed hits in bowl-out.

1. Yasir Arafat
2. Umar Gul
3. Shahid Afridi